# Visual Studio and Xamarin: Unable to find packages

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having problems trying to use Xamarin with Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 10. I use the Visual Studio Installer to get the Mobile Development tools, including Xamarin, but when I create a Cross-platform template of type Mobile app (Xamarin.Forms) I get a few error messages saying:

> - Error    NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Forms. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source
> - Error    NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source
> - Error    NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source
> - Error    NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source
> - Error    NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source
> - Error    NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source
> - Error    NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Forms. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source App2    C:\Users\rca_r\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\App2\App2\App2\App2.csproj*

So I can do basically nothing. Seems like a problem with paths or references, I don't know. I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like its trying to read from some offline Nuget feed. Go into your nuget config from Visual Studio and sort things out

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I went to Tools -> Nuget Packet Manager -> Packet Manager Settings and unchecked an offline source, I guess the was the default source of Microsoft. And now the errors changed to 'Error NU1100 Unable to resolve 'Xamarin.Forms (>= 2.5.0.280555)' for 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0/win-x86'. I guess I just messed up everything.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems Visual Studio is trying to find the packages only among the offline package sources, while they are available on NuGet. I would suggest first checking your internet connection and then checking the NuGet Package sources.

In Visual Studio go to **Tools** -> **NuGet Package Manager** -> **Package Manager Settings**. Here select the **Package Sources** tab in the tree on the left. You should see the following:

[image]

If the `nuget.org` package source is missing, add it manually by clicking the green plus button in the top right corner and setting:

- Name: `nuget.org`
- Source: `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: You are lifesaver for me. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :-) !